# ASP.NET MVC Custom Validation business logic

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I am trying to implement some custom validation but I am struggling with some logic .

The rule for the validation is simply an employee with `employeeID` Cannot request more than one holiday in a specific date range.

So for example if an employee with an `employeeID` has a holiday request for `StartDate` '01/01/2019' and `FinsihDate` '05/01/2019'

Then they request another request for
`StartDate` '03/01/2019' and `FinsihDate` '04/01/2019'.

Then the validation would handle this.

I'm just not sure how to implement this with the logic side of this as I'm not overly familiar with c#

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;

namespace HolidayTracker.Models
{
public class ValidSimilarRequests : ValidationAttribute
{
    private LotusWorksEntities db = new LotusWorksEntities();
    protected override ValidationResult
            IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {




        var model = (Models.HolidayRequestForm)validationContext.ObjectInstance;

        int empID = Convert.ToInt32(model.EmployeeID);

        DateTime _startdate = Convert.ToDateTime(model.StartDate);
        DateTime _finishdate = Convert.ToDateTime(model.FinishDate);

        var holidayexist = db.HolidayRequestForms.Any()

        if (holidayexist)
        {
            return new ValidationResult
                ("A holiday Request for this date range has already been requested");
        }


        else
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }


    }
}
```

}

Model:

```
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public partial class HolidayRequestForm
{
    public int RequestID { get; set; }

    [ValidSimilarRequests(ErrorMessage =
        "A holiday Request for this date range has already been requested")]
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }

     [ValidSameWeek(ErrorMessage =
        "Holiday Request Must be made on a weekly Period")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MMM/yy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public System.DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    [ValidStartFinishDate(ErrorMessage =
        "Finish Date can not be Greater than Start date.")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MMM/yy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public System.DateTime FinishDate { get; set; }

    [Range(0.0001, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Hours Requested must be greater than zero. ")]
    public decimal HoursTaken { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public int YearCreated { get; set; }
    public int MonthCreated { get; set; }
    public int DayCreated { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> YearOfHoliday { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Approved { get; set; }
    public string SubmittedBy { get; set; }
    public string ApprovedBy { get; set; }

    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put it in to your Any. Something like this:

`var holidayexist = db.HolidayRequestForms.Any(x=>x.EmpID==empID && x.Startdate>_startdate && x.Enddate < _enddate));`

Of course I don’t know exacly how your HolidayRequestForm Object is built up put I hope you get what I mean.

Comment: Did'nt seem to work! I was able to enter a form with dates in the same range

Comment: Have you checked the other way around?  I get sometimes confused with the greater than signs.

Comment: Seems to have done it! Quick question if you dont mind. It does'nt show the error message but an error screen! is this something wrong in the code?

Comment: I think the Message gets put in to an Exception what leads to the error screen. You have to catch it before that in your Controller and put it in to your ModelState. `ModelState.AddModelError("your message")`. Then it should be shown on your view.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for all the help pal!